# Spring Data - Unexpected cross join

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm working with a java web application based on Spring. In order to access to the database I'm using Spring Data 1.11.6.RELEASE with Hibernate 5.2. My database is MySQL 5.7

The involved entities are
- BaseEntity with some common fields

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @CreatedBy
    private WebUser createdBy;
    ...
    ...
}
```

The advertising

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "advertising")
public class Advertising extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne
    private AdvertisingStatus status;

    ...
    ...
}
```

And finally the WebUser

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "web_user",uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"mail"}))
public class WebUser extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne
    private WebUserStatus webUserStatus;

    ...
    ...
```

I'm not understanding why starting from this HQL and the Pageable object with maxRows = 75

```
from Advertising a 
where a.status in (:adStatuses) 
    and a.createdBy.webUserStatus.id = :webUserStatus 
order by orderDate desc
```

The generated query is the following

```
select *
from advertising advertisin0_ 
    cross join web_user webuser1_ where advertisin0_.createdBy_id=webuser1_.id 
    and (advertisin0_.status_id in (1 , 9)) 
    and webuser1_.webUserStatus_id=1
order by advertisin0_.orderDate desc limit 75
```

My concern is about the cross join, that should be slower than the standard join.
Is it possible to do a standard join instead of the cross join?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but it says [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) that *"In MySQL, JOIN, CROSS JOIN, and INNER JOIN are syntactic equivalents (they can replace each other)."*

Comment: If you want a SPECIFIC join type then you don't use syntax like "a.createdBy.webUserStatus" and instead do EXPLICIT JOINs in the FROM clause. As per what any basic JPQL doc would say

Comment: Thank you Nikos. My fault. I've experience in MS SQL Server but not in MySQL. Neil I've not asked for a specific join type. But thank you for your cooperation

Comment: There is no prescriptive recipe for translating JPQL to SQL so it is up to the JPA provider to make the translation. In the case of Hibernate (tagged on this question), this translation involves a `Dialect` appropriate for the underlying database (MySQL from the tags). Hibernate dialects [are known to produce different SQL](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7707) for the same situation, so it is not surprising to see a `CROSS JOIN` in the given case. Like @NeilStockton mentioned, if a particular join type is preferred, it is better to state that explicitly in the query.